# DNS doesn't work for mobile broadband (22.04 LTS)

Tags: networking, network-manager, ubuntu-touch, dns

While I can connect to mobile broadband with Ubuntu 22.04 and I can transmit packets (`ping 8.8.8.8` works fine), DNS resolution doesn't work. The result is that I can't use the internet connection.

This is the output of `nslookup google.de`:

```
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

I've tried fiddeling with the settings in `/etc/systemd/resolved.conf` as suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/991981/843526). Setting a fallback DNS server doesn't work at all. Overriding the DNS server does (once I restart systemd-resolved). The problem is that I can't set a fixed DNS server, as I use VPNs extensively and I need to use a DNS server for name resolution within the VPN. The DNS server is set via network-manager, so I don't want to hardcode it.

The content of `/etc/resolv.conf` is:

```
nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0 trust-ad
search .
```

Does anyone have any idea how to fix this? The Q&A I've referenced above is pretty old and I'd image the bug in the packet that is discussed there has been fixed since then.

Comment: This one probably will be a workaround https://askubuntu.com/a/1041631/1595094

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the cause of this. It was not the DNS lookup after all, but it's a bug in Ubuntu's network-manager module that was introduced in 1.35.91-1. It's described [here](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/NetworkManager/NetworkManager/-/issues/944). The problem is that ipv6 isn't enabled correctly for the mobile broadband connection and the DNS server that is automatically configured in systemd-resolved is an ipv6 server only. That's why it's unreachable, but at least it's configured correctly.

Unfortunately I can't downgrade to a network-manager version that still works, as the Ubuntu 22.04 apt repo doesn't include an older version.

Setting a static global DNS server in `/etc/systemd/resolved.conf` works as a workaround after all. It doesn't seem to override the VPN's DNS server.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the main issue is that somehow **systemd-resolved** ignoring it's own **/run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf**. Because when I am connecting my VPN I see that the correct nameserver being added there. But it makes no difference whatsoever. Probably some misconfiguration or I do not understand how it is supposed to work.